# NoClassDefFoundError with SwallowedExceptionListener in apache.commons

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-commons

I have this Runtime Exception. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. 
I've downloaded `apache commons dbcp2` from apache's site.

So far so good, but now, I add that module by File > Project Structure.

[Module addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJGy8.png)

As you can see I've done that same steps for MySQL Library, and its fine, all works; In fact, when I'm typing functions that appear in that `apache common` package doesnt appears any error. For example `BasicDataStructure`

```
public static DataSource getDataSource(){
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setUrl(JDBC_URL);
    ds.setUsername(JDBC_USER);
    ds.setPassword(JDBC_PASS);

    ds.setInitialSize(3);
    return ds;
}
```

But at time to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool2/SwallowedExceptionListener
at datos.Conexion.getDataSource(Conexion.java:19)
at datos.Conexion.getConnection(Conexion.java:33)
at test.ManejoPersonas.main(ManejoPersonas.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.SwallowedExceptionListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

This is my `.iml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
 <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
  <exclude-output />
  <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
   <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
  </content>
  <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
  <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  <orderEntry type="module-library" exported="">
   <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Documents/JAVA Libraries/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</orderEntry>
<orderEntry type="module-library" exported="">
  <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/Documents/JAVA Libraries/commons-dbcp2-2.7.0-bin/commons-dbcp2-2.7.0/commons-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
 </orderEntry>
</component>
</module>
```

And I dont know why, because while I'm coding there arent any problem.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you also need [Apache Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/download_pool.cgi) dependency in the project which is missing.

Comment: So... I only need download `Apache Commons Pool` and import it as I did with `Apache commons jdbc` ?

Comment: Hopefully, yes. Note that if there are any other transitive dependencies, you will have to add them as well. It may be easier to use Gradle or Maven so all the dependencies are fetched automatically.

Comment: Hmm, ok, that fine I'll do it. Thanks a lot for your time